# PHP 5: Sort multidimensional array by nested value or, conditionally, a second nested value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sorting

I think this is simple, I just get confused trying to organize how this should be done in my head.

The general form of the problem looks like:

```
<?php 
$array_to_sort(
           0 => array(
                     'element1' => array(),
                     'PrimarySortKey' => int
                     'element2' => array(
                                        'SecondarySortKey' => int
                                         )
                     )
           1 => array(
                     'element1' => array(),
                     'PrimarySortKey' => int
                     'element2' => array(
                                        'SecondarySortKey' => int
                                         )
                     )

           n => array(
                     'element1' => array(),
                     'PrimarySortKey' => int
                     'element2' => array(
                                        'SecondarySortKey' => int
                                         )
                     )
           );
?>
```

If it isn't evident from this model, the goal is to sort by `PrimarySortKey`, unless they prove to be equal, in which case sort by `SecondarySortKey`.

Reading the PHP Manual leaves me with the impression that this will either be some complicated instance of `array_multisort()` or else an `array_walk()` function, but I can never figure this sort of thing out. : /

I'm not asking anyone to write the function for me, but I'd appreciate help with the approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An implementation using [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) would be as follows:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a['PrimarySortKey'] == $b['PrimarySortKey']) {
        if ($a['element2']['SecondarySortKey'] == $b['element2']['SecondarySortKey']) {
           return 0;
        }
        return ($a['element2']['SecondarySortKey'] < $b['element2']['SecondarySortKey']) ? -1 : 1;
    }
    return ($a['PrimarySortKey'] < $b['PrimarySortKey']) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($array_to_sort, 'cmp');
```

Comment: Flawless, thanks very much, I hadn't even known about usort. :)

Answer (score 1):

So look at the function [PHP usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

Working example:

```
$arr = array(
        array('PrimarySortKey'=>30,'SecondarySortKey'=>3),
        array('PrimarySortKey'=>1,'SecondarySortKey'=>1),
        array('PrimarySortKey'=>30,'SecondarySortKey'=>9)
    );

    print_r($arr);

    usort($arr,function($a,$b){
       $key_a = $a['PrimarySortKey'];
       $key_b = $b['PrimarySortKey'];
        if($key_a == $key_b){
            $s_key_a = $a['SecondarySortKey'];   
            $s_key_b = $b['SecondarySortKey'];   

            return ($s_key_a < $s_key_b) ? -1 : 1;      
        }
        else{
            return ($key_a < $key_b) ? -1 : 1;      
        }

    });

    print_r($arr);
```

Prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [PrimarySortKey] => 30
            [SecondarySortKey] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [PrimarySortKey] => 1
            [SecondarySortKey] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [PrimarySortKey] => 30
            [SecondarySortKey] => 9
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [PrimarySortKey] => 1
            [SecondarySortKey] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [PrimarySortKey] => 30
            [SecondarySortKey] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [PrimarySortKey] => 30
            [SecondarySortKey] => 9
        )

)
```

Comment: The only reason I chose Nelson's answer as the correct one is because his answer deals with the second/third dimensions of the example array. I completely follow your example and it entirely solves the question, but for someone very new to PHP (I'm not, I just can't manage arrays in my head to save my life, haha) an answer that matches the model is easier to follow. :) Thanks though!!!

Comment: Well - maybe you are not seeing - but me too - and I was the first one - but that is ok - I'll gave you a full copy-paste code that works. and I think this is the best way to teach. you can broad my answer anyway your like - It's not good to feed you with a spoon. It's up to you in the end. glad to help